# Hibernate lazy attribute loading. False positive field detection with @DynamicUpdate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have a Hibernate entity with a lazy attribute.

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "rule", schema = "mariott_rule")
@DynamicUpdate // this is important
public class Rule {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "rule_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "switch")
    private boolean switched;

    @Column(name = "rule_name")
    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Column(name = "date_update")
    private ZonedDateTime dateUpdated;

    @Column(name = "param_values", columnDefinition = "text")
    @Convert(converter = RuleParamValuesAttributeConverter.class)
    @Basic(fetch = LAZY)
    private RuleParamValuesValidatedEntity paramValues;
}
```

And I have two methods that can either switch off or switch on the rule. Before switching the rule on we have be sure that `paramValues` are valid. That's why we fetch them with a separate query. But for the vice-versa operation it's not important. So, `paramValues` are not loaded in this case.

But here comes the strange part. The switching on operation generates the expected SQL.

```java
validateParamValues(rule.getParamValues());
ruleRepository.saveAndFlush(
    rule.asBuilder()
        .switched(true)
        .dateUpdated(now)
        .build();
);
```

```sql
update mariott_rule.rule set date_update=?, switch=? where rule_id=?
```

Meantime the switching off operation adds `paramValues` to result SQL and assigns its value to `"null"` (the string value of `null` word).

```java
// NO param values fetching
ruleRepository.saveAndFlush(
    rule.asBuilder()
        .switched(false)
        .dateUpdated(now)
        .build();
);
```

```sql
update mariott_rule.rule set date_update=?, param_values=?, switch=? where rule_id=?
binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2021-04-09T08:10:28.423406Z]
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
binding parameter [3] as [BOOLEAN] - [false]
binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [1]
```

Perhaps it's something about `RuleParamsValuesAttributeConverter.class`.

I removed the `Basic(fetch = LAZY)`. Though it did help that's not what I want. Any ideas?

P.S. BTW, when I removed `Basic(fetch = LAZY)` it seems that `@DynamicUpdate` stopped to work either.

**EDIT:**

Here is the `JsonAttributeConverter` and `RuleParamValuesAttributeConverter`

```java
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class JsonAttributeConverter<A> implements AttributeConverter<A, String> {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    private final Class<A> entityClass;
    private final String dbColumnName;
    private final A defaultValue;

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(A attribute) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(attribute);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ConvertException(String.format("Cannot convert %s to string", entityClass.getSimpleName()), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public A convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(dbData, entityClass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.warn(
                    String.format(
                        "Cannot convert database column %s to the %s. The default value shall be used",
                        dbColumnName,
                        entityClass.getSimpleName()),
                    e
                );
            }
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@Converter
public class RuleParamValuesAttributeConverter extends JsonAttributeConverter<RuleParamValuesValidatedEntity> {
    public RuleParamValuesAttributeConverter() {
        super(RuleParamValuesValidatedEntity.class, "mariott_rule.rule.param_values", RuleParamValuesValidatedEntity.getInvalidInstance());
    }
}
```

Comment: [@DynamicUpdate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-managed-state-dynamic-update) does not have any impact on the lazy attribute loading. It has impact on the SQL UPDATE statement generation only. You should use [bytecode enhancement](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement) for the lazy attribute loading.

Comment: Without knowing what the `RuleParamValuesAttributeConverter.class` does and how your builder pattern works tis is impossible to answer. I also don't understand why updating values needs to lead to a new instance of the object, which I suspect is part of the problem due to no value assigned for the `paramValues` it will lead to assigning `null`. Which will be detected as a change and hence will do the update. I also doubt that dynamic update will work if you create new instances each time when needed instead of properly updating entities.

Comment: @SternK I'm using bytecode enhancement and lazy property fetching works correctly. The problem is about `update` sql generation

Comment: @M.Deinum builder acts like a regular one from Lombok. I added the code for the converters

Comment: @M.Deinum I have a suspicion about new instance creation too. But I haven't found any proofs that `@DynamicUpdate` requires the entity to be mutable yet

Comment: If the object is immutable how is hibernate going to track changes made to the entity. Hibernate tracks changes due to the proxy the managed instance is. As you are creating a new instance through the builder this proxy gets destroyed.

Comment: @M.Deinum Well, if I read a record from the database it means that entity is stored in the persistence context. It means that Hibernate could check whether the entity with the same id is already present and test the fields for the equality. But as far as I understood, it doesn't work in that way

Comment: Indeed it doesn't work that way.